# Angular filtering based on string length

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a an angular view which loops through JSON data and returns all of the values from a form; however each form submitted has null values in various places. I'd like to return data for each section but only return it if the string length in greater than 0. Is there an angular filter that could do this?

Here is my view data:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="n in [] | range:100">
<div class="calendar" ng-repeat="cal in calendar[n].year | filterKey:month">  
<div class="events">
 <div ng-repeat="(val, key) in cal">
  <a href="/events/{{key.day}}">
  <article class="eventslist">
   <div class="numberedDate">
   <h3>{{key.day}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="calInfo">
     <h5>{{key.title}}</h5>
     <p>{{key.summary}}&nbsp;<a>more</p>
     </div>
     </article>
     </a>
</div>
```

Here is an example of submitted JSON data:

```
{

_id: "53ee9f0fc6aed109c6d33cfc"
  __v: 0
  -year: {
    December: [ ]
    November: [ ]
    October: [ ]
    September: [ ]
    August: [ ]
    July: [ ]
    -June: [
     -{
       day: "21"
       title: "ok"
       summary: "ok"
       description: "ok"
       _id: "53ee9f0fc6aed109c6d33cfd"
       }
         ]
    May: [ ]
    April: [ ]
    March: [ ]
    February: [ ]
    January: [ ]
    }
}
```

For the month of June this works well, but for the other 11 months it would be great to not return any data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enter a loop invariant to make it so you can loop through N elements in each pass?

```
<script>
var objectJson = /*the object that you get in JSON*/;
var structID = objectJson._id;

$_.each( objectJson, function( i, j) {
    //check for each v = 0 for every structID given the JSON ID

    if($(this).objectJson.structID.v = 0) {
        //do what you want with it
    }
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try too use data-ng-if with your possible condition in your ng-repeat div..may be it will  work.